# Updating multiple objects in single transaction in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm adding a set of objects using entity framework in single context but want to be in a transaction. How I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at the [How to: Manage Transactions in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article on MSDN. Basically you would use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class to demarcate the boundaries of the transaction.

Comment: Currently I'm using TransactionScope. Is it affects performance?

Answer (score 2):

If you call `SaveChanges` only once for all your changes you already have transaction because `SaveChanges` internally checks if the thread has associated transaction (for example via `TransactionScope`) and if it doesn't it will internally create a new one by calling `connection.BeginTransaction`.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is I'll create a Template object and following TemplateLayouts object that has a property as TemplateId. To get the TemplateId first I've to call the SaveChanges after the AddObject method is called then one more SaveChanges after all the layouts are added. I want to combine all in single transaction.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Your TemplateLayout should have Template property and by setting this property to a new Template instance EF will handle everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create transaction object on context connection object, then you can use transaction commit or rollback with regular mechanism or transaction scope.

```
dbContext.Connection.BeginTransaction()
```